# $\exp_q^{-1}(\exp_p(tX)) = \exp_q^{-1}(p)+t\Gamma_{p\to q}(X)+O(t^2)$ as $t\to 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with induced metric $d$ and [injectivity radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#I) $r>0$. Let $p, q$ be two points in $M$ such that $d(p,q)<r$. It is easy to see that $p$ and $q$ can be connected by an unique minimizing geodesic $\gamma=\{\gamma(t):0\le t\le 1 \}$ with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$. Denote by $\Gamma_{p\to q}:T_p(M)\to T_q(M)$ the [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport#Parallel_transport_in_Riemannian_geometry) along the geodesic $\gamma$ from $p$ to $q$.

> **My question is:** for a tangent vector $X\in T_p(M)$, does the following holds
>   $$\exp_q^{-1}(\exp_p(tX)) = \exp_q^{-1}(p)+t\Gamma_{p\to q}(X)+O(t^2), \quad t\to 0?$$

Any comments or hints will be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not hold : On $2$-dimensional unit sphere, consider two points of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ distance. And parallel vector field on the geodesic between two points is perpendicular to the geodesic (cf. Parallel transportion for Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below - Petrunin) :

When $M=\mathbb{S}^2,\ |p-q|=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $c$ is unit speed
geodesic from $p$ to $q$. Assume that $X(t)$ is a unit parallel
vector field along $c(t)$ s.t. $X(0)\perp c'(0)$.

Then $$A=0,\ B=\exp_p^{-1}\ q,\ C=\exp_p^{-1}\ \exp_q\ tX(\pi/2)$$ is
a triangle in $T_pM$ s.t. $\angle\ BAC = t$.

When $A,\ B,\ C'$ is triangle with $\angle\ ABC'=\pi/2$ and
$|B-C'|=t$, then we find $|C-C'|$ : By cosine law, \begin{align*}
|C-C'|^2&=t^2+(\pi\ \sin\ \frac{t}{2})^2-2t(\pi \ \sin\
\frac{t}{2})\cos\ \frac{t}{2} \\& =( t-\pi\ \sin\ \frac{t}{2})^2+ O(t^4)
\\ |C-C'| &=t-\pi\ \sin\ \frac{t}{2}+ O(t^2)\end{align*}

Comment: How does your example negate that equality? Can you explain more? Thanks...

Comment: I think I understand your exmaple and it is really a good counterexample. But I derive the last two equations in your answer as $$|C-C'|^2 = (t- \frac{\pi}{2} \sin t)^2 + (\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} \cos t)^2 = t^2 - \pi t \sin t + \frac{\pi^2}{2} (1-\cos t) = (1-\pi+ \frac{\pi^2}{4}) t^2 + O(t^4),$$ $$|C-C'| = (1-\frac{\pi}{2}) t + O(t^2).$$ But, anyway, this negate that equality in my question. Thanks.